# Multiple consumers in crossbeam example

Tags: rust, crossbeam

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I just started to play around with rust. To increase speed, I took a look at crossbeam:
The content of the channel should be processed by several thread at the same time. On the one hand a wait condition for the threads is missing (instant termination) and the parallel processing is not working as expected. Here is a small example:

```
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;
use crossbeam_utils::thread;
use crossbeam_utils::thread::scope;


// heavy processing
fn process(s:&str) {
    println!("receive: {:?}", s);
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
}

fn main() {
    let files_to_process = vec!["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv", "file4.csv", "file5.csv"];
    let (s, r) = crossbeam::channel::unbounded();
    for e in files_to_process {
        println!("sending: {:?}", e);
        s.send(e).unwrap()
    }

    drop(s);
    let clonned_r = r.clone();

    scope(|scope| {
        for _ in [0..3] {
            scope.spawn(|_| {
                match clonned_r.recv() {
                    Ok(s) => process(s),
                    _ => panic!("something went wrong")
                }
            });
        }
    }).unwrap();
}
```

Output:

```
sending: "file1.csv"
sending: "file2.csv"
sending: "file3.csv"
sending: "file4.csv"
sending: "file5.csv"
receive: "file1.csv"
```

Expected Output: Every "file" is displayed (and processed in parallel)

The documentation is missing an example how to setup several consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would run Clippy (Tools->Clippy in the playground) you would get a hint:

```
warning: for loop over a single element
  --> src/main.rs:25:9
   |
25 | /         for _ in [0..3] {
26 | |             scope.spawn(|_| {
27 | |                 match clonned_r.recv() {
28 | |                     Ok(s) => process(s),
...  |
31 | |             });
32 | |         }
   | |_________^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::single_element_loop)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#single_element_loop
help: try
   |
25 ~         {
26 +             let _ = 0..3;
27 +             scope.spawn(|_| {
28 +                 match clonned_r.recv() {
29 +                     Ok(s) => process(s),
30 +                     _ => panic!("something went wrong")
```

This is because `for _ in [0..3]` runs only **once**. This is a loop over an array of ranges with one element: `0..3`, and thus will yield one element: this range - `0..3`. To loop three times, do `for _ in 0..3`.

However, note that even after doing that it will only process three files - as you spawn only three threads with no looping but have five files. You'll have to either spawn more threads, loop and divide the work between a constant number of threads, or the best, use an existing library like [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me (one) of the issues. I was not able to get it running with crossbeam, but now get it with rayon - thank you again.